# Print the value of a variable of unknown type without newline in Octave

Tags: printf, octave, newline, disp

I mean to print the value of a variable `myvar` of unknown type, concatenated with arbitrary text, without a newline.

I know how to print without a newline: `printf('My var = %<format specifier>, is it ok for you?', myvar)`, but this requires knowing the type of `myvar`.

I know how to print the value of a variable of unknown type: `disp(myvar)`, but this always prints a newline (besides the fact I wouldn't know how to concatenate via `disp`).

**How would I get `My var = <any variable>, is it ok for you?<no newline>` printed?**

Comment: Does “unknown type” include custom classes with overloaded `disp` method?

Comment: @CrisLuengo - In principle, yes. But just including builtin types (albeit possibly complex, since nested structures, e.g., are also possible) would be quite good.
For instance, I want to use this on the values of all properties for an arbitrary object, so they can be quite varied.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that. Octave just doesn't really work like that.

What you **could** do, however, is have prepared sprintf-generated strings, which you can plug into your output. E.g.

```
var1 = 123;    % double
var2 = 'abc';  % char
var3 = cell(); % cell

Var = var2;   % choose from var1, var2, or var3

switch class(Var)
  case {'double'}, FormattedStr = sprintf('Value is %d', Var);
  case {'char'}  , FormattedStr = sprintf('Value is %s', Var);
  case {'cell'}  , % ... etc
  otherwise      , FormattedStr = sprintf('Value is unknown');
end

fprintf( 'As I said before: %s', FormattedStr);
```

Alternatively, you can create a "toString" function that tries to detect the type and return an appropriate string representation.

If you *really* want to use the output of disp, then in theory you *could* use `fdisp` to write to a file, and then read back from that file and process the newlines out accordingly. But I think this is overkill.

Comment: All options are overly complex for a seemingly simple action. Having a `-nonewline` flag for `disp` (or the like) seems so simple...

Comment: This is because `disp` is a _display_ function. It would not make sense. What you need is a "string formatting" function. Which assumes you want to format your variable in a particular way. Not knowing the type of what you're printing is a pretty impossible scenario. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I don't see it impossible and, in fact, there a quite a few languages that allow for this (including Octave with `disp`!).
What I mean to do is exactly what is asked. Printing in a way that I don't have to care about the type, and being able to continue printing on the same line.
I would trust the language to provide a good-enough format, exactly what I do with `disp`. I can always write a wrapper to catch exceptions to this rule in case the format provided is not-that-good. But I would be writing a mere zero to a-few such rules.
I cannot figure out how to explain it differently.